# What happens if a requests.Session is reused after remote disconnect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

If I create a `requests.Session()` and use it for several requests, if one of those requests were to throw an exception like this:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

Assuming I caught the exception and continued executing, what would happen if I used the session again? My understanding is that the object caches a TCP connection that can get used by multiple requests on the session, which I guess would get lost when this error occurs. Does the `Session` object try to reestablish the connection automatically, or would I need to do that in the exception handler? If I do, is there a way to tell the `Session` to try reestablishing the connection if it happens to fail?

Here is a code segment that would cause the above to happen:

```
sess = requests.Session()
try:
    response = sess.get('http://someapi.com')
    response = sess.get('http://someapi.com') # throws requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    response = sess.get('http://someapi.com') # what happens here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to verify using a minimal reproducer that the session will indeed try to connect again on the event of a remote disconnect the next time a request is made.

The reproducer consists of two files. `server.py` is a simple webserver that asks for command line input whenever it gets a GET request. Given 'y', it sends a response, and given 'n' it does not. `test.py` implements similar code to the example in the question. By inputting the sequence 'y', 'n', 'y' into the server, it can be shown that the session in `test.py` will succeed on the final request.

server.py (based on https://pythonbasics.org/webserver/)

```
# Python 3 server example
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 8080

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        userin = input('y/n:')
        if userin == 'y':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(bytes("response text", "utf-8"))

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

test.py

```
import requests

sess = requests.Session()

try:
    print(sess.get('http://localhost:8080'))
    print(sess.get('http://localhost:8080'))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(sess.get('http://localhost:8080'))
```

server.py output

```
Server started http://localhost:8080
y/n:y
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2022 11:43:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
y/n:n
y/n:y
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2022 11:43:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

test.py output

```
<Response [200]>
('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
<Response [200]>
```